# Short story: Man gains X-ray vision, cheats at cards, sees a clot in his blood

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, powers

I remember reading it close to 10 years ago: a man acquired the ability to see through objects. He used it to cheat at cards, and later, saw through his own flesh and divined a blood clot approaching his heart, threatening his life.

I believe it was a short story, and that it did **not** take place in the future but rather the present or past.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Check out the [suggestions for story-id questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you recall any additional details, like where you might have read it.

Comment: [Henry Sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wonderful_Story_of_Henry_Sugar_and_Six_More)?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is probably [The Wonderful Story of Henry Sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wonderful_Story_of_Henry_Sugar_and_Six_More), a short story by [Roald Dahl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roald_Dahl).  I had not remembered the clot bit but a little online searching found it:

> He looks at the place in his chest where the pain is coming from. . .
>   and he sees. . . or thinks he sees. . . a small dark lump inside the
>   big vein leading into the heart on the right-hand side. What could a
>   small dark lump be doing inside the vein? It must be a blockage of
>   some kind. It must be a clot. A blood-clot!

It is set in the present, although some aspects of that present will now seem a bit dated.  Henry does learn to see through cards with practice:

> His job now, he told himself, was to keep practising and practising
>   with the cards until he could see through them instantly. He was
>   convinced it could be done. Already, on the second go, he had knocked
>   four seconds off his time. He would give up working with the candle
>   and concentrate solely upon the cards. He would keep at it day and
>   night.

And while he used his skill to cheat at cards, in the end, he arrived at a nobler goal:

> With the money I make, I will set up an absolutely first-class
>   orphanage in every country I visit. I will become a Robin Hood. I will
>   take money from the bookmakers and the gambling proprietors and give it
>   to the children. Does that sound corny and sentimental? As a dream, it
>   does. But as a reality, if I can really make it work, it wouldn't be
>   corny at all, or sentimental. It would be rather tremendous.

Comment: Notice that the quoted text about the blood clot does not actually happen in the story. It is preceded by:
" Now, had this been a made-up story instead of a true one, it would have been necessary to inventsome sort of a surprising and exciting end for it. It would not be difficult to do that. Something dramaticand unusual. So before telling you what reallydid happen to Henry in real life, let us pause here for amoment to see what a competent fiction writer would have done to wrap this story up."

Comment: and afterwards: "That wouldn't be such a bad ending for a work of fiction, but this story is not fiction. It is true. The only untrue things about it are Henry's name and the name of the gambling casino. Henry's name was not Henry Sugar. His name has to be protected. It still must be protected. And for obvious reasons, one cannot call the casino by its real name. Apart from that, it is a true story."

Comment: followed by: "And because it is a true story, it must have the true ending. The true one may not be quite so dramatic or spooky as a made-up one could be, but it is nonetheless interesting. Here is what actually happened."

Comment: ...followed by??? Don't let us hanging!!

Comment: @Vincent: I think it's implied that this is followed by the actual rest of the plot, as described in this answer.  The Robin Hood part at least.

Comment: @Vincent, what Peter said, but you should read the story, it really is wonderful.